# Linux: Find out top 10 recently updated files / folders

Tags: linux, sorting, centos, diskspace, du

I would like to find out what were top consuming files or folders in linux, which consumes most space (in human readable form - in MB or in GB) files or folders should be recently modified - for example within last month.

I suspect this is combination of du -exec, sort, ls command, but can be specify which ?

Comment: I have the strong feeling that this has been asked and answered many times before on the internet. Please do some research before you post a question! Besides that, the question is off topic on SO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP showed no own effort to solve the problem

Comment: there were similar questions, but not with frequently modified date. So this is new question. I have tried to solve this on my own using stack overflow suggestions, but unfortunately without any result, that's why this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top consuming files modified within last month:

```
find "$PWD" -type f -mtime -30 -exec du -sh '{}' + | sort -rh | head
```

Top consuming folders modified within last month:

```
find "$PWD" -type d -mtime -30 -exec du -sh '{}' + | sort -rh | head
```

If your `sort` version doesn't support the `-h` option, you can try:

```
find "$PWD" -type f -mtime -30 -exec du -s '{}' + | sort -nr | head | cut -f2- | xargs -d'\n' du -sh
```

Comment: I have some older CentOS distribution, is it possible to survive without sort -h option, as it's not available (sort: invalid option -- h)

Comment: Please see updated answer. Also this might help you: https://serverfault.com/questions/62411/how-can-i-sort-du-h-output-by-size

Comment: Third command looks like working as I wanted. Takes a lot of time to execute on root however, needs to be pation.

Answer (score 1):

With CLI

```
du -hsc * | sort -h
```

What each option means for du:

```
h: show sizes in human readable format (1K, 1M, 1G, ...)
s: summarize: display only a total for each argument
c: also display a grand total
```

If you want GUI, you can use disk usage analyzer

Comment: I have some older CentOS distribution, is it possible to survive without sort -h option, as it's not available (sort: invalid option -- h)

Answer (score 0):

If you want really the top 10, you can use:

```
du -h | sort -h | tail -10
```

In CentOS, without `sort -h`, you can try this:

```
du -h | sort -nr | tail -10
```

Comment: I have some older CentOS distribution, is it possible to survive without sort -h option, as it's not available (sort: invalid option -- h)

Comment: Updated answer: sort -nr.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools such as https://www.diskreport.net/ to follow the graph of your disk usage history